# Python - Replace strings in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace some adresses in French in a dataframe. I'm using a list and regular expressions and one list.

```
def adresses(df):  

    liste_adresses = ['allée', 'Allée', 'rue', 'Rue', 'avenue', 'Avenue', 'av', 'AV', 'boulevard', 'Boulevard', 'bd', 'Bd', 'carreau', 'Carreau', 'carrefour', 'Carrefour', 'place', 'Place', 'voie', 'Voie', 'villa', 'Villa', 'route', 'Route', 'quai', 'Quai']

    for i in liste_adresses:

        df['C'] = df['C'].str.replace(r'[0-9]+(,|\s+)i\s+\w+\s+(\w+)?(\s+)?(\w+)?(\s+)?([0-9]{5})?(\s+)?\w+?([0-9]{5})?','<address>')

return df
```

**My dataframe:**

```
       A          B                                                                C
  French      house                      I live in 15 rue Louis Philippe 75001 Neuilly
 English      house               my address: 101-102 bd Charles de Gaulle 75001 Paris
  French  apartment                                                    my name is Liam
  French      house                                                       Hello George!
 English  apartment  This is wrong: 4, rue Ledion Paris 75014 and I'm not happy with it
```

On my output, nothing happens.

**Good output:**

```
       A          B                         C
  French      house                                I live in <address>
 English      house                              my address: <address>
  French  apartment                                    my name is Liam
  French      house                                       Hello George!
 English  apartment  This is wrong: <address> and I'm not happy with it
```

Comment: The problem about nothing happens is that the variable `i` that contains the elements of `liste_adresses` is embedded in the regex you define `'[0-9]+(,|\s+)i\s+\...'` so it is looking for the letter `i` not its value (for example `'allée'`). It would be more: `'[0-9]+(,|\s+)' + i + '\s+\...'` and then something happens although it is not the expected output.

Comment: In your full data, does the strings in the column `C` ends by the address? By this, I mean could have more character after such as `This is wrong: 4, rue Ledion Paris 75014 and I'm not happy with it`?

Comment: @Ben.T Not necessarily, I'll edit my dataframe. Thank you

Comment: ok, then it becomes a more difficult task to my opinion. Would you have a list of cities a bit the same way than `liste_adresses `? or you have to many cities in you data?

Comment: Many cities in my data :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution may not works for specific cases. Because the end of the address is either the postal code or the city that you don't know, I think one way could be to look for:

1. a string with numbers at first `'[0-9]+'`: all addresses start with a number
2. some characters `(.*)`: for example to catch `-102`
3. any word from `liste_adresses` using `'|'.join(liste_adresses)`
4. the postal code of 5 digits `[0-9]{5}`
5. look for the city name if existing with `([^\.|\n]{0,2}[A-Z][a-z]*)*`: here I assume that if there is a dot or a new line after the postal code, then the address is over, so match between 0 and 2 characters but not a dot or new line `[^\.|\n]{0,2}`, then one upper case letter `[A-Z]` then any lower case `[a-z]*` until the end of the word, the extra at the end `*` would catch cities composed of two words like Saint-Denis.

So globally, doing:

```
liste_adresses = ['allée', 'Allée', 'rue', 'Rue', 'avenue', 'Avenue', 'av', 'AV',
                  'boulevard', 'Boulevard', 'bd', 'Bd', 'carreau', 'Carreau',
                  'carrefour', 'Carrefour', 'place', 'Place', 'voie', 'Voie',
                  'villa', 'Villa', 'route', 'Route', 'quai', 'Quai']

reg = r'[0-9]+(.*)('+'|'.join(liste_adresses) + ')(.*)[0-9]{5}([^\.|\n]{0,2}[A-Z][a-z]*)*'

print (df['C'].str.replace(reg,'<address>'))
0                                  I live in <address>
1                                my address: <address>
2                                      my name is Liam
3                                        Hello George!
4    This is wrong: <address> and I'm not happy wit...
```